# Bulk Insert/Update into SQL Server database using .net

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to bulk insert (or update if record exists) more than 25000 rows of data into a SQL Server database using .net. Which approach is best for me ?

Eg:
If I send data to database it should insert / update those records.

Comment: Performing Batch Operations Using DataAdapters - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aadf8fk2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: A bulk operation doesn't support checking for existing rows or not. What you should do is **(1)** bulk insert your rows into a staging table - all of them, and then **(2)** compare that staging table to the real table you have and insert new rows, update existing rows. A bulk operation does just that - bulk load data, without checking, without comparing, without other manipulation - but it does this very quickly.

Comment: What version of SQL server: Beginning with SQL Server 2008, now you can use MERGE SQL command; so you can use SqlBulkCopy to bulkload into staging and after that merge to insert/update efficiently. Do not use linq-to-sql for that because it is painfully slow on batch based operations

Answer (score 2):

I think you need SqlBulkCopy class.

```
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);//Store your data into dataTable
```

Comment: This is step one: use SqlBulkCopy to insert into a staging table. Step two is to use a "Merge" statement to merge the data.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use XML updation method. pass data to the database in XML format**`

```
CREATE  procedure [dbo].[BulkInsertion]    
@xmlData NTEXT,  
@Type INT              
AS              
BEGIN              
DECLARE @idoc INT                  
EXEC SP_XML_PREPAREDOCUMENT @idoc OUTPUT, @xmlData                 
IF @Type=1    
BEGIN    
INSERT INTO TableName              
Column1, Column2, Column3
)           
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
)
END AS DOLP  
FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '//Table1', 3)                      
WITH    (Column1 INT, Column2 VARCHAR(250), Column3 VARCHAR(250))  
END            
EXEC SP_XML_REMOVEDOCUMENT @idoc    
END'
```

Comment: If this is not bulk insertion..then please tell what the above snippet means

Comment: Why would you do a C# bulkinsert of rows this way and your answer also does not address the merge..

Comment: Using xml is one legitimate option for doing a Set-Based operation.  You push the Xml down.  Shred it.  And perform an Insert/Update (or wired up a MERGE) based on a unique constraint.  I'm upvoting this since someone downvoted it.  Kalias, you're using the Sql Server 2000 OPENXML syntax, which (while backwards compatiable) .. isn't the most up to date method for 2005 and forward.  I would google "Plamen Shred Xml" for a more up to date .nodes method.

Comment: Thanks granadacoder for sharing the information. I have used OPENXML  successfully for updation, and  thats why i have shared it. Which is the most updated method for doing the same?